# Display Rating Bar in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, callisto

I have to display ratingbar rating from callisto. I want to only show ratings only (user can not give rating).

XAML:

```
<callisto:Rating Background="Transparent" x:Name="listingRatingDetail" Margin="0,0,0,0" Foreground="#FFFF6666" ItemCount="5" Value="{Binding Rating}" ReadOnlyFill="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" PointerOverFill="{x:Null}" PointerPressedFill="{x:Null}" FontSize="14"/>
```

How to apply it to only show ratings?

Note:

I using C# languange

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `IsEnabled` property to `false`? It makes the control read-only.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes it makes ratingbar can not be edited by user, but color ratingbar become older. How to keep the color original color?

Comment: You know what, you can actually just do  a workaround here. Put it inside a grid and add a rectangle on top of it with a transparent background:
`<Grid>
<callisto:Rating/>
<Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
</Grid>`

Comment: You could also restyle the control to remove the visual state for when it's disabled